# Returning an element from a List in Scala

Tags: scala, list

I've recently been working on a beginner's project in Scala, and have a beginner question about Scala's Lists.

Say I have a list of tuples ( `List[Tuple2[String, String]]`, for example). Is there a convenience method to return the first occurence of a specified tuple from the List, or is it necessary to iterate through the list by hand?

Answer (score 13):

```
scala> val list = List(("A", "B", 1), ("C", "D", 1), ("E", "F", 1), ("C", "D", 2), ("G", "H", 1))
list: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, Int)] = List((A,B,1), (C,D,1), (E,F,1), (C,D,2), (G,H,1))

scala> list find {e => e._1 == "C" && e._2 == "D"}
res0: Option[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, Int)] = Some((C,D,1))
```

Comment: Is it possible to return not Some((C,D,1)) but (C,D,1)? I mean the same way if I would use list(1).

Comment: @grass What should the return value be if the triple `(C,D,1)` is not found in the list?

Comment: None or exception or empty set. Would be great if there is a way to customize the return value if the triple is not found(except writing my own find() method).

Comment: 'None' and 'Some' always go together. They make an 'Option[T]'. If your function were to simply return 'T' you have to signal the no-such case by an exception. I'll add an answer soon that I think provides what you're wanting (using 'find').

Answer (score 6):

You could try using [find](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Find). (Updated scala-doc location of find)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a previous comment, `find` is probably the easiest way to do this.  There are actually three different "linear search" methods in Scala's collections, each returning a slightly different value.  Which one you use depends upon what you need the data for.  For example, do you need an index, or do you just need a boolean `true`/`false`?

Comment: Could you give more information on these "linear search" methods? I'm looking to get the index of a tuple (having only part of the tuple)

Comment: actually I've found what I was looking for: `.zipWithIndex.collect { case ("partOfTuple", _, i) => i }`

Answer (score 2):

If you're learning scala, I'd take a good look at the [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) trait. It provides the basis for much of scala's functional goodness.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this, which doesn't require knowing the field names in the Tuple2 class--it uses pattern matching instead:

```
list find { case (x,y,_) => x == "C" && y == "D" }
```

"find" is good when you know you only need one; if you want to find all matching elements you could either use "filter" or the equivalent sugary for comprehension:

```
for ( (x,y,z) <- list if x == "C" && y == "D") yield (x,y,z)
```

Comment: Your second example seems to function much more like `filter`, i.e. it will return *all* elements matching property, not the only first one as question author wants it to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that may help you.

I had a similar case, having a collection of base class entries (here, `A`) out of which I wanted to find a certain derived class's node, if any (here, `B`).

```
class A

case class B(val name: String) extends A

object TestX extends App {
  val states: List[A] = List( B("aa"), new A, B("ccc") )

  def findByName( name: String ): Option[B] = {
    states.find{
      case x: B if x.name == name => return Some(x)
      case _ => false
    }
    None
  }

  println( findByName("ccc") )    // "Some(B(ccc))"
}
```

The important part here (for my app) is that `findByName` does not return `Option[A]` but `Option[B]`.

You can easily modify the behaviour to return `B` instead, and throw an exception if none was found. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `collectFirst` which delivers `Some[(String,String)]` for the first matching tuple or `None` otherwise, for instance as follows,

```
xs collectFirst { case t@(a,_) if a == "existing" => t }
Some((existing,str))

scala> xs collectFirst { case t@(a,_) if a == "nonExisting" => t }
None
```

Using `@` we bind the value of the tuple to `t` so that a whole matching tuple can be collected.